# Summing a column value in a table including duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with duplicates like that:

```
ClassId Name    Days    SpecHours   
1       Jack    250     130
1       Jack    250     130
1       Jack    250     120
2       Mike    300     130
…
```

What I want is to sum totalSpecHours for non-duplicates. My expected output is:

```
ClassId Name    Days    totalSpecHours  
1       Jack    250     250
2       Mike    300     130
```

I am not able to manage to calculate the totalSpecHours. I am trying to use something like on below, but is doesnt work correctly.

```
totalSpecHours = sum(distinct SpecHours)
```

I try the equality on below, but it also doesnt work, but I guess I need something like that. I appreciate if someone helps. Thanks.

```
totalSpecHours= (sum(X.SpecHours in (select mt.ClassId, mt.SpecHours from myTable mt group by mt.ClassId, mt.SpecHours) as X))
```

Cheers.

Edit: Ty for the answers, most correct. First answer has been selected as the correct one. Appreciated all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select 
 classID, 
 Name, 
 Days, 
 sum(specHours) as TotalSpecHours 
from 
 (
 select distinct ClassId, Name, Days, SpecHours from myTable )t
  group by classID, Name, Days
```

**Logic:**

We take distinct values in inner query and then over this result set we do a group by and get the sum.
Please note that inner query is evaluated only once, so no performance issue.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't something like this work?

```
SELECT ClassId, Name, Days, SUM(SpecHours) AS totalSpecHours 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ClassId, Name, Days, SpecHours
    FROM Table 
) outer
GROUP BY ClassId, Name, Days
```

Comment: DhruvJoshi beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Group By:

```
SELECT ClassId, Name, Days, SUM(totalSpecHours) FROM
(
    SELECT ClassId, Name, Days, SpecHours AS totalSpecHours 
    FROM TableName GROUP BY ClassId, Name, Days, SpecHours
)
```

Comment: Not the downvoter. But OP does not want to sum absolute duplicate rows.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi: Ah. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE(Common Table Expression)

```
With CTE_Values as
(
Select distinct ClassID, SpecHours From MyTable
)
Select Sum(SpecHours) From CTE_Values
```

Comment: Op dont want to count spec hours if it is duplicate

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte
as
(
select 
classid,name,days,spechours,row_number() over (partition by classid,name,days,spechours order by spechours) as rn
from yourtable

)
select sum(spechours)
from cte c1
where not exists(select 1 from cte c2 where c1.classid=c2.classid and c1.rn>1)
```